# Static IP address issue with Ubuntu Server 12.04

Tags: networking, server

I gave a static IP address to my eth1 as follows:

```
Auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
address 192.168.xx.xx
netmask 255.255.255.0
Gateway 1xx.xx.xx
```

I saved the file, and afterwards I did the following:

```
sudo nano /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base
```

and wrote as below:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.8.4
```

and saved it.

I am getting the below error when I try to down the Ethernet adapter.

```
/etc/network/interfaces :2: misplaced option
ifdown : couldn't read interface file "etc/network/interfaces"
then I restarted the Server and upon starting I observed the below
Starting configure network devices --- FAIL
Starting configure Virtual devices ---- FAIL
```

BUT......! When I do the following everything works fine:

```
sudo ifconfig eth1 192.168.xx.xx netmask 255.255.255.0
```

but these are temporary.

Another thing that puzzled me is after configuring a static IP I opened the /etc/network/interface but it was blank. Strangely enough once I purge IP settings using `IP addr flush eth1`, I can open the interface file, with all the static IP settings intact. Any idea what's going on? I would appreciate all your help as I am literally "dead in the water".

Comment: I tried to configure multiple IP addresses on the same interface. so eth0 has everything, address, netmask, network, broadcast, gateway, dns, and the rest of three (eth0:0 , eth0:1 and eth0:2) have only address and netmask when restarting networking I receive the following: ifup: could't read interfaces file "/etc/network/interfaces"
/etc/network/interfaces:35: unknown method Help anyone?

Comment: Sorry I'm so late to the party, but maybe this will help someone else. If you're getting a DHCP address assigned by the router, I would presume that your router has DHCP enabled. Have you configured your router to provide static addresses?

Answer (score 1):

While configuring static ip address , You can configure nameserver by `dns-nameservers` as shown in below. You don't need to configure /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base. 
Here is my contents of /etc/network/interfaces.

```
    auto eth0

    iface eth0 inet static
            address 192.168.11.21
            netmask 255.255.255.0
            network 192.168.11.0
            broadcast 192.168.11.255
            gateway 192.168.11.1
            dns-nameservers 192.168.11.1
```

Comment: Hi Patel, well now I can't go to network/interfaces.  When I type sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces it opens up a new file and not the one i was working ..... i am totally confused right now

Comment: You can copy content shown in answer and modify as per your configuration.

Comment: I did that too.... when the PC boots us I see "Starting Network Configuration FAIL"3 time & "Starting Virtual Network Configuration FAIL" also, but once I run ip addr flush eth1 I can go back & open interface file. I see all the setting intact there.....

Comment: Patel, as soon as I change the static IP to DHCP an run the comman sudo dhclient -v eth1.... the connection comes back and everything is working fine, but since this box gonna be a server I need to be able to give a static IP Adress..... appreciate if you know how to fix this

Comment: Nilanga Try this commmand
ifconfig eth0:0 192.168.0.41 netmask 255.255.255.0 broadcast 192.168.0.255

Comment: It seems that it is bug. Please reinstall network-manager.